# SQL Server : conditionally add rows and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column as

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| Sl. No. | bal1 | bal2 | bal3 | status1 | status2 | status3 |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|    1    | 520  | 270  | 351  |    1    |    0     |    1   |
|    2    | 201  | 456  | 154  |    0    |    1     |    1   |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to add the rows field for Status value = 1 in SQL Server

eg. result

```
--------------------
| Sl. No. | amount |
--------------------
|    1    |   871  | // bal1 + bal3 as the status1 and status3 is 1
|    2    |   610  | // bal2 + bal3 as the status2 and status3 is 1
--------------------
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `CASE status1 WHEN 1 THEN bal1 ELSE 0 END + CASE status2 WHEN 1 THEN bal2 ELSE 0 END + CASE status3 WHEN 1 THEN bal3 ELSE 0 END`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it using `CASE`

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c0cf/4)

```
SELECT [SI. No.], 
       (case when status1 =1 then bal1 else 0 end +
       case when status2 =1 then bal2 else 0 end +
       case when status3 =1 then bal3 else 0 end)  as balance

from Table1
```

Answer (score 3):

If the `status` values will always be 1 or 0, you can multiply and add:

```
select [Sl. No.], bal1 * status1 + bal2 * status2 + bal3 * status3
from table
```

Comment: Clever idea! Good on you @adrift

Comment: Curious about the downvote.  This will provide the same result as the multiple case statements, and I expect would perform better.

Comment: Wasn't me but do you have any evidence this will perform better? Even if it does, does it justify the cryptic and not-quite-self-documenting approach? What happens if the status columns change to a different type (like CHAR(1) to support `'Y'`/`'N'` or TINYINT to support additional status types)?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT [Sl. No.], 
   (case when bs.[status1] =1 then bs.bal1 else 0 end +
   case when bs.status2 =1 then bs.bal2 else 0 end +
   case when bs.status3 =1 then bs.bal3 else 0 end)  as amount
from BalStatus AS bs
```